# Shorthand and nicer python syntax for four options clicking a button

Tags: python

I have a var `af_button` which is a button on UI. It can be either selected or deselected, so in that case I have four possibilities, which I have implemented. I don't like this implementation, so what would be a more pythonic way of implementing this?

```
af_button = squishtest.waitForObject("{text='AF' type='QPushButton' unnamed='1' visible='1'}")
if state == 'click':
    if af_button.checked == 1:
        pass
    else:
        squishtest.clickButton(squishtest.waitForObject(af_button))
else:
    if af_button.checked == 0:
        pass
    else:
        squishtest.clickButton(squishtest.waitForObject(af_button))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do an `if: pass`? Just check if the case is not true by using the not equal to operator and make the `else` section be the point.

```
if state == 'click':
    if af_button.checked != 1:
        squishtest.clickButton(squishtest.waitForObject(af_button))
else:
    if af_button.checked != 0:
        squishtest.clickButton(squishtest.waitForObject(af_button))
```

You could shorten this further and clearer by combining the two conditions then:

```
if state == 'click' and af_button.checked != 1:
    squishtest.clickButton(squishtest.waitForObject(af_button))

elif state != 'click' and af_button.checked != 0:
    squishtest.clickButton(squishtest.waitForObject(af_button))
```

Answer (score 4):

If 0 and 1 are the only possible values of `af_button.checked`, you could condense this to just one `if`:

```
if (state == 'click') != af_button.checked:
    squishtest.clickButton(squishtest.waitForObject(af_button))
```

The parentheses are important because otherwise Python would treat this as a chained comparison. `(state == 'click')` evaluates to `True` or `False`, and `True` equals 1 and `False` equals 0.